# Procedimiento Update MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

3. Crear un procedimiento para actualizar el precioventa de los productos de manera que:

a. Si el precioventa es menor que la media se aumenta el
precioventa en un 10%

b. Si el precioventa es mayor que la media se aumenta en un 5%

El procedimiento tiene que recibir el codigoproducto de los productos.

Mostrar por pantalla una tabla con las siguientes columnas :
codigoproducto, precioventa antes de actualizarlo y precioventa después de
actualizarlo.

Yo lo he intentado de esta forma pero el PrecioVenta que se muestra es 0... ¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo? Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
drop procedure if exists procedimiento1;

DELIMITER //

create procedure procedimiento1 (in codproducto int(5))

begin

update productos 
    set PrecioVenta= case 
        when PrecioVenta<(select avg(PrecioVenta)) then PrecioVenta+(PrecioVenta*0.10)
        when PrecioVenta>(select avg(PrecioVenta)) then PrecioVenta+(PrecioVenta*0.05)
    end
    where CodigoProducto=codproducto;

select CodigoProducto, PrecioVenta from productos where CodigoProducto=codproducto;

end//

DELIMITER //

call procedimiento1 (11679);
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es `PrecioVenta` en la tabla?

Comment: @A.Cedano numeric(15,2)